# Quick way to loop through all data.tables in workspace

Tags: r, data.table

How can I loop through each data.table in my workspace?  I know `tables()` will print all available data.table names but I'm not sure how to reference the actual objects.

Thanks

Comment: `mget` most likely...?

Comment: what @joran said; also, don't do this

Comment: @joran Thanks, I'm not sure how I didn't see that.  If you put that as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve multiple objects from an environment (like the global workspace) all at once using `mget`, which is just a vectorized version of `get`. For example:

```
x <- 1
y <- 2
z <- 3
> mget(c("x","y","z"))
$x
[1] 1

$y
[1] 2

$z
[1] 3
```

But I agree with @eddi that the need to do this sort of thing will usually attract some level of scolding for not having placed your data.tables in a single list to begin with.